Calculating Kraus operators from joint Unitary on System and Environment
Can someone please explain to me why when we calculate the Kraus operators (the action of a unitary $U$ on a restricted system we have $$M_{j} = \langle j|U|0\rangle\,,$$
where $j \in \text{Span(Environment)}$.
However, I don't understand what the $|0\rangle$ is there for. Perhaps it is not only ever $|0\rangle$, but in all the examples I looked at, it was. I can't figure out where this comes from.

Starting from the system-environment form of a $d$-dimensional channel
$$
\Phi(\rho):={\rm tr}_E(U(\rho\otimes|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)U^\dagger)
$$
where the environment is in the pure state $|\psi\rangle$, the Kraus operators of $\Phi$ are precisely $M_j=\langle j|_EU|\psi\rangle_E\in\mathbb C^{d\times d}$ (where $j$ runs from $0$ to $d_E-1$, with $d_E$ the environment dimension). The point is that the Kraus operators depend not only on $U$, but also on the state the environment is initialized in. And if $|\psi\rangle=|0\rangle$, i.e., if the environment is initially in the basis state $|0\rangle$, then you recover the formula you asked about.
As an aside, if the environment starts out in a mixed state $\omega=\sum_{i=1}^mr_i|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|$, then you have even more Kraus operators: $\sqrt r_i\langle j|_EU|\psi_i\rangle_E$, $i=1,\ldots,m$, $j=0,\ldots,d_E-1$. In other words operators of the form $\langle j|_EU|0\rangle_E$ could—up to rescaling—also appear for mixed environment, but then there would necessarily be more Kraus operators than just the ones you listed in your question.

Ah okay, this makes more sense, so for the depolarizing channel, with action $U|x0\rangle $, where $x$ is a qubit, then the $|0\rangle$ term in $M_{j}=\langle j|U|0\rangle $ is coming from the fact that the initial state of the environment is $|0\rangle$ (from $U|x0\rangle $)? Although, in this particular example, the environment is spanned by $|0\rangle, |1\rangle, |2\rangle, |3\rangle$, in this case $j$ doesn't run from $1$ to the environment dimension?

That's exactly right; also thanks for pointing out that mistake of mine on $j$, I adjusted my answer accordingly.
